# ActiveX component can’t create object : PCOMM.autECLConnList

Tags: excel, vba, com, activex, common-controls

I am trying to automate the sending keystrokes to a mainframe application which is being connected using PCOMM iSeries emulator. I am not sure on what I am doing wrong here, as the same code works on a different machine.
Below are the configurations,

> **Working Machine**  : Windows 10 64 bit, Office 32-Bit
>
> **Error Machine** : Windows 7 64 bit, Office 64-Bit

Below is the code

```
On Error Resume Next

Set autECLWinObj = CreateObject("PCOMM.autECLConnList")

Set IA = CreateObject("PCOMM.autECLOIA")
Set PS = CreateObject("PCOMM.autECLPS")

PS.SetConnectionByName (Client)
IA.SetConnectionByName (Client)
autECLWinObj.SetConnectionByName (Client)
```

Please help, i am new to this and stuck .

P.S : Kindly don't duplicate the question as there are none specific to PCOMM.

Comment: I'm quite sure this needs a lot more information. Have you tried in other machines with similar setup? Has it worked earlier? Isn't there really any actual error anywhere?

Comment: Hi @JamesZ, no i wasn't unable to try on other machine with the same configuration. The error is in the line where `Set autECLWinObj = CreateObject("PCOMM.autECLConnList")` would be having **nothing**. Please let me know if you need more inputs.

Comment: well if it works on one version of windows and not another, its a configuration issue of some sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed MS Office 64 to MS Office 32 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

PCOMM only provides 32-bit dlls for the automation objects, so those can not be used from a 64-bit process (like 64-bit office).

See also [this IBM support entry](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IC99468).

Answer (score 0):

You must upgrade you IBM Personal Communications to the new Version 14 (64 bits) since may 2019